# async/await, not waiting for the variable to populate before printing

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

```
async function filterusers(users){
    let usersfiltered=[]
    for(var i = 0;i < users.length; i++){
        let userref = db.collection('usernames').doc(users[i]);
        let getDoc = userref.get()
          .then(doc => {
            if (doc.exists) {
              usersfiltered.push(users[i])
            }
          })
    }
    return await usersfiltered;
}

filterusers(users).then(console.log);
```

i am looking to wait for the filtered result but it always prints blank array ie before the result is being returned.

Comment: You're mixing `await` and `then` in the same scope of execution. Choose one of them, and use only that one.

Comment: Also, with `usersfiltered` being an array, what exactly are you hoping to achieve with `await usersfiltered`??? You can `await` on a promise object, no more and no less.

Comment: To be precise, one can `await` any expression and it will return the value itself if it's not a Promise. But you are right about `await`'s misused here. Reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Answer (score 2):

```
async function filterusers(users){
    let usersfiltered=[]

    // You should use let or const instead of var.
    for(let i = 0;i < users.length; i++){
        // I believe getting doc needs await.
        let userref = await db.collection('usernames').doc(users[i]);
        await userref.get()
          .then(doc => {
            if (doc.exists) {
              usersfiltered.push(users[i])
            }
          })
    }
    return usersfiltered;
}

filterusers(users).then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself by moving the `await` to before `userref.get()`

```
async function filterusers(users){
    let usersfiltered=[]
    for(var i = 0;i < users.length; i++){
        let userref = db.collection('usernames').doc(users[i]);
        let getDoc = await userref.get()
          .then(doc => {
            if (doc.exists) {
              usersfiltered.push(users[i])
            }
          })
    }
    return usersfiltered;
}

filterusers(users).then(console.log);
```

Comment: Better for you to collect the promises and use `Promise.all` to await them instead or awaiting one by one. That way the runtime will be the max time of all requests instead of the sum of them.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to turn the array of users into an array of Promises ( asynchronous operations) by using `Array.map`:

```
const checkUserPromises = users.map((user) => {
  const userref = db.collection("usernames").doc(user);
  return userref.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      return user;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });
});
```

Then, you need to `await` these promises with `Promises.all`:

```
const checkedUsers = await Promise.all(checkUserPromises);
```

Lastly, you may want to filter out the users that are not existing:

```
const existingUsers = checkedUsers.filter((user) => user !== null);
```

Answer (score 0):

await should be with Promise

```
async function filterusers(users) {
  let usersfiltered = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    let userref = db.collection("usernames").doc(users[i]);
    let getDoc = await userref.get();

    if (getDoc.exists) {
      usersfiltered.push(users[i]);
    }
  }
  return usersfiltered;
}

let filterdUsers = filterusers(users);
console.log(filterdUsers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not mix *async/await* with *.then*.

Secondly, use new ES6 *for loops*, to make the code work properly with async/await.

```
async function filterusers(users) {
      let usersfiltered = [];
      filterusers(users).then(console.log);

      for (const user of users) {
        let userref = db.collection('usernames').doc(user);
        const doc = await userref.get();
        if (doc.exists) {
          usersfiltered.push(user);
        }
      }
      return await usersfiltered;
    }
```

Comment: "Firstly, do not mix async/await with .then." Can you explain this?